# Notation - Sum over unique pairs in a set

Tags: notation

I have a family of numbers $x_{i_1,i_2}$ where $i_1\in{I}$, $i_2\in{I}$, and $I=\{1,2,3\}$. If I wanted to sum every value of $x$, I could write:
$$
\sum_{i_1\in I}\sum_{i_2\in I}x_{i_1,i_2}
$$

However, I only want to sum unique pairs, and not the elements where $i_1=i_2$. I.e., the equivalent of:
$$
\sum_{i_1=1}^2\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^3x_{i_1,i_2}
$$
or
$$
x_{1,2}+x_{1,3}+x_{2,3}
$$

#### Question:

Is there a clean notation for this that doesn't require using integer indexes?

Comment: How about

$$\large\underset{i_1\lt i_2}{\sum_{i_1\in I}\sum_{i_2\in I}} x_{i_1,i_2}$$

Comment: One fairly common notation for subsets of cardinality $k$ is $[A]^k$. You could write $\sum_{(i,j) \in [I]^2} x_{i,j}$. I am not sure how much more clarity this adds to the notation in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to specify conditions in the indices:

$$
\sum_{i_1\in I}\sum_{{i_2\in I}; i_2>i_1}x_{i_1,i_2}
$$